# Firebase/Firestore users access and roles how it works?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to figure out how the role system works with Firebase but I'm extremely confused and don't understand how it all works.

I think I understood that to give a role to a user you have to use either Firebase Admin SDK or the security rules on Firestore.

However I don't understand the difference and why one would be more efficient than the other and how it works.

For example:

I have a delivery application with only 2 roles: delivery person and admin

The deliverers have a mobile application that indicates the address where the package should be delivered.

The admin has access to the same interface as the delivery person on the mobile application but has access to a web application to manage the deliveries. He can add a delivery, a driver etc...

How does Firebase authentication work and how to use role assignment correctly?

Is making a call to the "user" database to know if he is admin or normal user as soon as he logs in a good way to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this is a little large so I can't provide code snippets for it. But I can point to a example project that hase an "atomic" role system. You can check it out [here](https://github.com/TarikHuber/react-most-wanted/tree/master/packages/rmw-shell/cra-template-rmw/template).

The basics. You can save the roles of a user in the databes (RTDB or Firestore). If you need both databases sync them between both to have single system.

The main point is that each user can only read his own roles and if he is an admin.
The changes to that data should only work using the firebase cloud functions.
To check if a user is admin or has a role make a simple "exists" check for the authenticated user and if the corresponding role or admin status exists for him.

In firestore you can even have helper functions like those here:

```js
    //Checks if user is signed in
    function isSignedIn() {
      return request.auth.uid != null;
    }

    //Checks if user has admin rights
    function isAdmin() {
      return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/admins/$(request.auth.uid))
    }

    //Checks if user has a specific grant
    function hasGrant(grant) {
      return  get(/databases/$(database)/documents/user_grants/$(request.auth.uid)).data[grant]==true
    }

    //Checks if user is granted either as admin or with a grant
    function isGranted(grant){
      return isAdmin() || hasGrant(grant);
    }


    //Checks if user has specific UID
    function isOwner(userUid){
      return request.auth.uid == userUid 
    }
```

Some would say to use the `customClaims` but I would never recommend that. Maybe only for the admin status and not more. The have a to small size to have any larger roles system on them. By storing the roles into the databases you can have them changed even in realtime.

To get the roles and is admin status for a user just make a realtime listener for that data.